# PropTypes check of object with dynamic keys

Tags: reactjs

React has lots of ways of using PropTypes to check the value of a prop. One that I commonly use is `React.PropTypes.shape({...})`. However, I recently came across a situation where I have an object that will have dynamic key/values inside. I know that each key should be a string (in a known format), and each value should be an int. Even using a custom prop validation function, it still assumes you know the key of the prop. How do I use PropTypes to check that both the keys and values of an object/shape are correct?

```
...
someArray: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
  // How to specify a dynamic string key? Keys are a date/datetime string
  <dynamicStringKey>: React.PropTypes.number
}))
...
```

So again: I want to at the very least check that the value of each key is a number. Ideally, I would also like to be able to check the the key itself is a string in the correct format.

Comment: `import { objectOf }  from 'prop-types'`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> **Note**: This answer was written in 2015 when the current version of React was 0.14.3. It may or may not apply to the version of React you're using today.

That's an interesting question. From your question it sounds like you've
read about custom type checkers in the docs for [Prop Validation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).
For posterity I'll reproduce it here:

> ```javascript
> // You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
> // object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
> // won't work inside `oneOfType`.
> customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
>   if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
>     return new Error('Validation failed!');
>   }
> }
> ```

When implementing type checkers I prefer to use React's built-in type
checkers as much as possible. You want to check if the values are
numbers, so we should use `PropTypes.number` for that, right? It would
be nice if we could just do `PropTypes.number('not a number!')` and get
the appropriate error, but unfortunately it's a little more involved
than that. The first stop is to understand...

### How type checkers work

Here's the function signature of a type checker:

```javascript
function(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) => null | Error
```

As you can see, all of the props are passed as the first argument and
the name of the prop being tested is passed as the second. The last
three arguments are used for printing out useful error messages and are
optional: `componentName` is self-explanatory. `location` will be one of
`'prop'`, `'context'`, or `'childContext'` (we're only interested in
`'prop'`), and `propFullName` is for when we're dealing with nested
props, e.g.  `someObj.someKey`.

Armed with this knowledge, we can now invoke a type checker directly:

```javascript
PropTypes.number({ myProp: 'bad' }, 'myProp');
// => [Error: Invalid undefined `myProp` of type `string` supplied
//     to `<<anonymous>>`, expected `number`.]
```

See? Not quite as useful without all of the arguments. This is better:

```javascript
PropTypes.number({ myProp: 'bad' }, 'myProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop')
// => [Error: Invalid prop `myProp` of type `string` supplied
//     to `MyComponent`, expected `number`.]
```

### An array type checker

One thing the docs don't mention is that when you supply a custom type
checker to `PropTypes.arrayOf`, it will be called for each array
element, and the first two arguments will be the array itself and the
current element's index, respectively. Now we can start sketching out
our type checker:

```javascript
function validArrayItem(arr, idx, componentName, location, propFullName) {
  var obj = arr[idx];

  console.log(propFullName, obj);

  // 1. Check if `obj` is an Object using `PropTypes.object`
  // 2. Check if all of its keys conform to some specified format
  // 3. Check if all of its values are numbers

  return null;
}
```

So far it'll always return `null` (which indicates valid props), but we
threw in a `console.log` to get a peek at what's going on.  Now we can
test it like this:

```javascript
var typeChecker = PropTypes.arrayOf(validArrayItem);
var myArray = [ { foo: 1 }, { bar: 'qux' } ];
var props = { myProp: myArray };

typeChecker(props, 'myProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop');
// -> myProp[0] { foo: 1 }
//    myProp[1] { bar: 'qux' }
// => null
```

As you can see, `propFullName` is `myProp[0]` for the first item and
`myProp[1]` for the second.

Now let's flesh out the three parts of the function.

#### 1. Check if `obj` is an Object using `PropTypes.object`

This is the easiest part:

```javascript
function validArrayItem(arr, idx, componentName, location, propFullName) {
  var obj = arr[idx];
  var props = {};
  props[propFullName] = obj;

  // Check if `obj` is an Object using `PropTypes.object`
  var isObjectError = PropTypes.object(props, propFullName, componentName, location);
  if (isObjectError) { return isObjectError; }

  return null;
}

var typeChecker = PropTypes.arrayOf(validArrayItem);
var props = { myProp: [ { foo: 1 }, 'bar' ] };
typeChecker(props, 'myProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop');
// => [Error: Invalid prop `myProp[1]` of type `string` supplied to
//     `MyComponent`, expected `object`.]
```

Perfect! Next...

#### 2. Check if all of its keys conform to some specified format

In your question you say "each key should be a string," but all object
keys in JavaScript are strings, so let's say, arbitrarily, that we want
to test if the keys all start with a capital letter. Let's make a custom
type checker for that:

```javascript
var STARTS_WITH_UPPERCASE_LETTER_EXPR = /^[A-Z]/;

function validObjectKeys(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) {
  var obj = props[propName];
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);

  // If the object is empty, consider it valid
  if (keys.length === 0) { return null; }

  var key;
  var propFullNameWithKey;

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    key = keys[i];
    propFullNameWithKey = (propFullName || propName) + '.' + key;

    if (STARTS_WITH_UPPERCASE_LETTER_EXPR.test(key)) { continue; }

    return new Error(
      'Invalid key `' + propFullNameWithKey + '` supplied to ' +
      '`' + componentName + '`; expected to match ' +
      STARTS_WITH_UPPERCASE_LETTER_EXPR + '.'
    );
  }

  return null;
}
```

We can test it on its own:

```javascript
var props = { myProp: { Foo: 1, bar: 2 } };
validObjectKeys(props, 'myProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop');
// -> myProp.Foo Foo
//    myProp.bar bar
// => [Error: Invalid key `myProp.bar` supplied to `MyComponent`;
//     expected to match /^[A-Z]/.]
```

Great! Let's integrate it into our `validArrayItem` type checker:

```javascript
function validArrayItem(arr, idx, componentName, location, propFullName) {
  var obj = arr[idx];
  var props = {};
  props[propFullName] = obj;

  // Check if `obj` is an Object using `PropTypes.object`
  var isObjectError = PropTypes.object(props, propFullName, componentName, location);
  if (isObjectError) { return isObjectError; }

  // Check if all of its keys conform to some specified format
  var validObjectKeysError = validObjectKeys(props, propFullName, componentName);
  if (validObjectKeysError) { return validObjectKeysError; }

  return null;
}
```

And test it out:

```javascript
var props = { myProp: [ { Foo: 1 }, { bar: 2 } ] };
var typeChecker = PropTypes.arrayOf(validArrayItem);
typeChecker(props, 'myProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop');
// -> myProp[0].Foo Foo
//    myProp[1].bar bar
// => [Error: Invalid key `myProp[1].bar` supplied to `MyComponent`;
//     expected to match /^[A-Z]/.]
```

And finally...

#### 3. Check if all of its values are numbers

Happily, we don't need to do much work here, since we can use the
built-in `PropTypes.objectOf`:

```javascript
// Check if all of its values are numbers
var validObjectValues = PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number);
var validObjectValuesError = validObjectValues(props, propFullName, componentName, location);
if (validObjectValuesError) { return validObjectValuesError; }
```

We'll test it below.

### All together now

Here's our final code:

```javascript
function validArrayItem(arr, idx, componentName, location, propFullName) {
  var obj = arr[idx];
  var props = {};
  props[propFullName] = obj;

  // Check if `obj` is an Object using `PropTypes.object`
  var isObjectError = PropTypes.object(props, propFullName, componentName, location);
  if (isObjectError) { return isObjectError; }

  // Check if all of its keys conform to some specified format
  var validObjectKeysError = validObjectKeys(props, propFullName, componentName);
  if (validObjectKeysError) { return validObjectKeysError; }

  // Check if all of its values are numbers
  var validObjectValues = PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number);
  var validObjectValuesError = validObjectValues(props, propFullName, componentName, location);
  if (validObjectValuesError) { return validObjectValuesError; }

  return null;
}
```

We'll write a quick convenience function for testing and throw some data
at it:

```javascript
function test(arrayToTest) {
  var typeChecker = PropTypes.arrayOf(validArrayItem);
  var props = { testProp: arrayToTest };
  return typeChecker(props, 'testProp', 'MyComponent', 'prop');
}

test([ { Foo: 1 }, { Bar: 2 } ]);
// => null

test([ { Foo: 1 }, { bar: 2 } ]);
// => [Error: Invalid key `testProp[1].bar` supplied to `MyComponent`;
//     expected to match /^[A-Z]/.]

test([ { Foo: 1 }, { Bar: false } ]);
// => [Error: Invalid prop `testProp[1].Bar` of type `boolean` supplied to
//     `MyComponent`, expected `number`.]
```

It works! Now you can use it in your React component just like the
built-in type checkers:

```javascript
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  someArray: PropTypes.arrayOf(validArrayItem);
};
```

Of course, I would recommend giving it a more meaningful name and moving
it into its own module.

Comment: The amount of detail in here is awesome, thank you. Knowing about those two extra args when working on an array is very useful!

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect for checking normalized data in maps with key = id.

Comment: As a follow up, the following code is useful to look at and illustrates how React itself calls the validators - [code on github](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9a42f8a0c51320384bae5e105e16aa4954990b81/src/isomorphic/classic/types/__tests__/ReactPropTypes-test.js).

Comment: Note that calling the PropType functions directly will be deprecated in a future major release: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: TLDR; use `PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number)`

Answer (score 117):

To validate **only** the values, you can use `React.PropTypes.objectOf`.

```
...
someArray: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
  React.PropTypes.objectOf(React.PropTypes.number)
)
...
```

Comment: This is the correct solution IMHO as it succinctly answers the question.

Comment: For reference it's documented here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 33):

The Problem for me was ...

- Object has dynamic keys **(which i don't wanna check)**
- Values have a fixed data structure **(which i wanna check)**
- Shape of the underlying data structure is known and can be checked

  ```
  // An object with property values of a certain shape
  optionalObject: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      fontSize: PropTypes.number
    })
  );
  ```

So for my problem the missing part was `PropTypes.objectOf` from there you are able to create any type of structures with dynamic keys.
Also in combination with `PropTypes.oneOfType` it becomes very flexible.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which specifically asked how to also validate that the keys within the object matched a certain format.

Comment: Hey @MatthewHerbst that's true. 
I am not answering the question 100% correctly, but since it solved my problem in an easy way i thought maybe someone else will come along and find this code snippet useful.
Many people search by Topic, and i guess i match the topic here. But i adjusted the post to be more clear what this solution is missing.

Comment: I tried validating an object with dynamic keys for dynamic forms. This answer solves checking the object inside the keys which has come very useful. Thanks @teberl

Comment: Does not answer the OPs question exactly, but does answer mine. Thanks

Comment: Even though this isn't quite what the OP wanted, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: what do you do if you have a dynamic object where all values are strings but only one is boolean?
`{ myBoolean: true, a: 'a', b: 'b', ...}` I used to had this `PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,` but fails with that fixed key `myBoolean`

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own validator by passing a function.

See `customProp` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation).

I believe you can do something like `React.PropTypes.arrayOf(customValidator)`.

Here's the validator you're looking for:

```
function objectWithNumericKeys(obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj).some(key => isNaN(key)))
     return new Error('Validation failed!');
}
```

Comment: I know that - I mentioned it in the question. What I'm asking is, what if I don't know the value of the key, or `customProp` in this case?