# check if the key in an object is string or not when using prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a following kind of props need to be checked

```
const columns = {
  name: {
    key    : 'company',
    label  : 'Company',
  },
  employee: {
    key  : 'employee',
    label: 'Employee',
  },
}
```

Using flow i would check this in the below way

```
[key: string]: { // the key is dynamic
      key: string,
      label?: string,
}
```

How can i do such checks when using prop-types? I am very new to this.

Update

```
<Table
  isSearchable
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
/>
```

The `column` props will always be an object with a `key value` approach where `key` should always be string and `value` should be an `object of key(name) and label`

may be the terms is creating the confusion so i am updating the columns props as

```
const columns = {
  name: { // how do i check name which is a key and is dynamic
    uniqueName    : 'company',
    displayName  : 'Company',
  },
  employee: {
    uniqueName  : 'employee',
    displayName: 'Employee',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PropTypes package assumes that props are named and known ahead of time. While it might be technically possible to check run arbitary checks on keys (I'm eyeing up custom validators and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362898/proptypes-check-of-object-with-dynamic-keys/34365401#34365401)), I think you're in for a **very** hard time. I'd like to frame challenge and suggest an alternative.

Instead of passing an object that looks like this:

```
const columns = {
    name: {
        uniqueName    : 'company',
        displayName  : 'Company',
    },
    employee: {
        uniqueName  : 'employee',
        displayName: 'Employee',
    },
};
```

Pass columns as an array of columns. The benefit here is that it's dead simple to check with PropTypes, and I'd imagine much eaiser to reason about in code.

```
function App() {
    const columns = [
        {
            column: 'name',
            uniqueName: 'company',
            displayName  : 'Company',
        },
        {
            column: 'employee',
            uniqueName: 'employee',
            displayName  : 'Employee',
        },
    ];

    return (
        <Report
            columns={columns}
        />
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Report(props) {
    const { columns } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {columns.map( (column) => {
                return (
                    <p key={column.column}>
                        {column.column}
                    </p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

Report.propTypes = {
    columns : PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            column: PropTypes.string,
            uniqueName: PropTypes.string,
            displayName: PropTypes.string
        })
    )
};

export default Report;
```

In my own projects, I'd take it a step further and make `Column` a class of it's own and check it with `PropTypes.instanceOf`:

```
const columns = [
    Column.init( { ... } ),
    Column.init( { ... } ),
]

... 

Report.propTypes = {
    columns : PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Column))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PropTypes.shape` with `PropTypes.oneOfType`

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.shape({
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
  }),
]);
```

Check out [this example](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)

Comment: Could you explain this more? I'm a bit confused about the use of `oneOfType`, as I understand it a string isn't a valid prop - only the shape? Also, the docs you linked suggest that `PropTypes` is imported from it's own package, is it also accessible from `React`? Why is label a number?

Comment: I understood `PropTypes.shape` part but for dynamic keys how would `PropTypes.oneOfType` works?

Comment: number was just an example, I switched it back to string.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a field that could either be a string OR an object like you've shown above?  `oneOfType` allows it to be one of the supplied types.  So it can either be an object with the fields `name` and `label` or it can just be a `string`.

Comment: and to answer your question on React.PropTypes vs prop-types package
https://alligator.io/react/the-new-proptypes/

Comment: The `column` props will always be an object with a `key value` approach where key should always be string and value should be an object of `key(name) and label`

Comment: In that case you can just use the `PropTypes.shape({})` part, no need for `PropTypes.oneOfType([])`

Comment: `PropTypes.shape({})` will check only the value(label, key) parts not the key of an object.

Comment: why would you need to check that?

Comment: so that other developer knows that the key should only be string not a number

Comment: Typically you're the one who provides the name of keys in the PropTypes, if you're doing this with dynamic key names you could checkout part 2 of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365401/2694189