# Prop-Types in React for custom object keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have an object type like this:

```
interface DataType {
    labels: string[];
    datasets: {
        [key: string]: number[]
    };
}
```

And I am trying to define it's prop-type as this:

```
data: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.exact({
        labels: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
        datasets: PropTypes.objectOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
            })
        )
    })
).isRequired,
```

But I am getting this error:

```
(property) data?: Validator<DataType> | undefined
Type 'Validator<{ [x: string]: Required<InferProps<{ labels: Validator<(string | null | undefined) 
[]>; datasets: Requireable<{ [x: string]: InferProps<{ data: Requireable<(number | null | undefined) 
[]>; }> | null | undefined; }>; }>> | null | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 
'Validator<DataType>'.
Type '{ [x: string]: Required<InferProps<{ labels: Validator<(string | null | undefined)[]>; 
datasets: Requireable<{ [x: string]: InferProps<{ data: Requireable<(number | null | undefined)[]>; 
}> | null | undefined; }>; }>> | null | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 
'DataType': labels, datasets ts(2322)
```

Can someone help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your `datasets` property in `PropTypes.objectOf()`. I think your proptypes is breaking because you have used `[key :string]` in the `DataType` declaration. As the error indicated, `data` is undefined for the type `DatType`.

Here's an example object I created using `DataType`

```js
{
    "labels": ["string1","string2"],
    "datasets": {
        "data" : [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

and here is proptypes structure :

```js
data : PropTypes.shape({
  labels: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  datasets: PropTypes.shape({
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
  }).isRequired
}).isRequired;
```

Comment: So how should I declare the type of "DataType", because it is parsed output of some API response, and there can be any key there that is string?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362898/proptypes-check-of-object-with-dynamic-keys help?